# Can't Access C$ Over Domian

Tags: networking

I am trying to access \computer\c$

When I do that it shows me the login box and says "Access Denied". I am a domain admin and on all other machines when I do \computer2\c$ it normally works.

For this machine I have tried.

```
net use \\address\c$ user:computer\admin
```

And it says access denied. When I try to login using the normal method to this share in the security box even with the local admin it says Access Denied.

When I use the following

```
net use \\address\c$ user:domain\MyAccount
```

It says Error 5 Access denied.

I am able to remote desktop into the computer as myself with no problem. This is causing a problem with some of my servers trying to access log files from windows where it says the location is not available.

I have looked through the security log and under the Audit Failure for my attempts to login it says.

"A handle to an object has been requested" as an Audit Failure.

I am entirely confused. This is not a UAC problem as I have tried that fix and that does nothing and as I said all the other machines besides this one on the domain are working normally.

It also shows a special logon success as well as a logoff success for a second which means I logged on successfully and then it logged me off.

For those machines when I do a \computer\c$ it opens the C Drive for that computer without a problem.

**EDIT 1:** Clocks are synced with the server correctly.

**EDIT 2**: Normal method of me is going to \computer\c$ and it just opens. With this problem it brings up a security box and under username and passwords it says "Access Denied".

**EDIT 3:** Tried 
`\\Address\c$` 
and it says I do not have permission to access this share.

**EDIT 4:** Added more information.

Suggestions?

Comment: Just because you are an Domain Admin does not mean you can read access to the share.  Just because you don't have that access does not mean you can't give it to yourself.  I honestly have no idea what method is the "normal method" might want to clarify that.

Comment: @Ramhound Updated question for "Normal Method". Also the Domain Admins are a group in the local computer's Adminstrator Group. That means Domain Admins have access to the whole machine per my understanding of hierarchy and shares.

Comment: Verify the share permissions.  Its possible to have a share only accessible by Users but not Administrators.  *This has nothing to do with the C programming language.*

Comment: @Ramhound I have checked permissions of C: and it says Administrators (Domain\Domain Admins) has access and full control.

Comment: Windows looks at the lowest user group to determine permissions.  So if your Domain user is now part of the local machine's User Group, you also have to add that group, to the list of allowed User Groups.  *Based on your error message, I can safety say, the user does not have access to the share.*

Comment: @Ramhound The 2 groups on the machine  are Users and Administrators. Domian Admins is part of the Administrators. I am still a little confused. The c$ share is a build it administrator share so there should be no reason why I am unable to access the drive even as the local domain admin

Comment: Can a different domain administrator access the share?

Comment: @Ramhound no. I have even used the local admin account. I even set the C Drive to be shared by EVERYONE and it still says access denied.